# Play Spotify song preview in audio element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, spotify

I am trying to build a feature on my web application that pulls the preview url from Spotify's API, and play the preview when the user clicks on the audio controls. I am able to save the correct URL in the source, but the song does not play. I looked at the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), but still could not get it to work. Here is a snippet of my code in JSX:

```
<div className="audio-container">
  <audio controls="controls">
    <source src={this.props.songs[2].href} type="audio"/>
  </audio>
  <p className="font-style">{this.props.songs[2].name}</p>
</div>
```

I do not receive any errors. Is there anything obvious I am missing? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who may find this useful later, I got the audio to work by removing the source tag and putting the preview url directly in the audio tag. Example:

```
<audio controls src="..."></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you use `type="audio/mpeg"`

Working example below:

```html
  <audio controls="controls">
    <source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/83090a4db6899eaca689ae35f69126dbe65d94c9?cid=null" type="audio/mpeg"/>
  </audio>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This did not fix my problem though. I still can't click on the controls.

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(this.props.songs[2].href);`?

Comment: Just looking at this [Spotify Reference](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-track/), are you sure {this.props.songs[2].href} is referencing `.preview_url`?

Comment: Ya I am positive I am querying the correct url, just poor naming convention. The url I get is something like: https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/b1c472f3d54cc67624bdc39c3bb09b8ecd7d0aa0?cid=a3e0a2d583904251b53a1f461ab54606